# How to target tooltip menu template item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using lite tooltip menu template option. I want to alert something on clicking one of the list items in the tooltip. I want to target the tooltip list item.

```
<td>
                <a href='#' class = 'sales_tooltip' data-templatename='Conifer' 
                    data-title='<div class = "tooltip-menu">
                                    <ul><li class="sales_rep"><a href="#">Sales Rep 1 </a></li>
                                        <li class="sales_rep"><a href="#">Sales Rep 2 </a></li>
                                        <li class="last-child sales_rep"><a href="#">Sales Rep 3 </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>'> 
                    <i class = 'fa fa-male ' aria-hidden='true'></i>    
                </a>

            </td>
```

Javascript code

```
$('a.sales_tooltip').find('.sales_rep').click(function(){

                alert('clicked');

                console.log("Tooltip clicked");
});
```

I am not able to target the li item in the tooltip.

I actually want to change the data-title attribute of `a.sales_tooltip`, to the list item clicked, on clicking it. This is what I tried.

```
$('body').on('click', '.tooltip-menu li.sales_rep', function() {

                    var $set_value = $(this).html();

                    $(this.closest('a.sales_tooltip')).attr('data-title', $set_value);



            });
```

Comment: Uh.. which tooltip plugin are you using? I am really not sure if you can write HTML inside a tooltip but I could be wrong. Try creating a fully working demo on jsFiddle for more clarity. Thanks

Comment: @Aziz I am using LiteTooltip. This is the js fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/ammunair/agu2tjp2/

Comment: Oh it's a commercial script? I'm not sure if the creators would be happy about you sharing the script in such a public fashion.. hmm.. have you tried consulting them about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li.sales_rep` elements are not child elements of the `a.sales_tooltip`, so you cannot use `$('a.sales_tooltip').find('.sales_rep')`.

This code is searching for elements with the class `sales_rep` which are child elements of `a.sales_tooltip`.

The tooltip library you are using is probably adding the tooltip elements to the body, so you can use

```
$('body').on('click', '.tooltip-menu li.sales_rep', function() {
    alert('clicked');
    console.log("Tooltip clicked");
});
```

## Update

After a long discussion it appears that the actual question was "how to change the content of the tooltip **after** it already has initiated?"

Well - in lite tooltip it's impossible to destroy/reset/reinit a tooltip.

The solution - when we need it - replace the original element (that has the tooltip) with a cloned element (same one), and create a new tooltip for that cloned element.

```
$('body').on('click', '.tooltip-menu li.sales_rep', function() {
    if (confirm("Have you chosen your sales rep?")) {
        var $set_value = $(this).html();
        var el = $('#'+ $(this).data('for'))
        var cloned_el =el.clone(); 

        cloned_el.attr('data-title', $set_value);
        el.replaceWith(cloned_el);
        cloned_el.LiteTooltip({ 
            location: 'left-bottom',
            trigger: 'hoverable',
            padding:0,
            margin:0
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

Here is a working demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrbABp

Comment: I actually want to change the data-title attribute of a.sales_tooltip, to the list item clicked, on clicking it.
Could you plz help ?

This is what I tried

    $('body').on('click', '.tooltip-menu li.sales_rep', function() {
   
      var $set_value = $(this).html();
      
      $(this.closest('a.sales_tooltip')).attr('data-title', $set_value);
      
     
    });

Comment: First of all I think you should use `$(this).closest` and not `$(this.closest`. Second - Since the tooltip element are **not** created near the `<a>` tag, I really don't think you will be able to get to the relevant `<a>` using the `closest()` function. Try to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with an example and it will be easier to help.

Comment: Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ammunair/agu2tjp2/

Could you plz help ? I have been stuck with this for so long.

Comment: Had some problem with updating your original jsfiddle, here is a codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrbvBX

Comment: Yes i could access it. Having a look.

Comment: I could access the code, but It is still not working :(
The data-title remains the same
Im trying. Anyhow thnku so much for your effort.
In case, you find a solution, please post it. Thanks again.

Comment: The `data-title` is changed. what you are looking is something else - you want the lite tooltip to regenerate the tooltip after you change that value. Regarding the answer - my answer is correct, please accept it.

Comment: Dear Dekel, After confirming, I want the tooltip to show only the value selected. Not the whole list. This is not happening for me. 
Is it happening this way for you ?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment - in order to do so you need to re-render the lite tooltip. You didn't say so from the beginning so I didn't do that (and this really isn't your original question). I really don't mind helping you, but after my work so far I think you should accept my answer.

Comment: I have no issues accepting the answer Dekel. As i said, your knowledge has helped me so much. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: any inputs on re-rendering the tooltip ?

Comment: Thankyou so much @Dekel

Comment: I dont have enough reputation points to display the points, but I have already upvoted your answer several times. You should have got the points, though it is not displayed here.

Comment: If you dont mind, can you have a look at this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907830/how-to-get-the-index-table-row-when-i-click-on-li-item-in-tooltip-menu-temp?noredirect=1#comment65174271_38907830

Comment: Could you please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907830/how-to-get-the-index-table-row-when-i-click-on-li-item-in-tooltip-menu-temp?noredirect=1#comment65174381_38907830

Comment: I just googled on how to accept the answer and did it. Sorry, I thought upvoting was same as accepting the answer. Sorry again.

Comment: Sure :) no problem