# How to get the index - table row -, when I click on li item in tooltip menu template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the code I am using. In my table, on hovering the sales column, I have a menu template tooltip that has 3 list items. When clicking on one of these li items, I want to know the table row/ index the sales column is in.
Code below:

```
<td>
    <a href='#' class = 'sales_tooltip' data-templatename='Conifer' 
        data-title='<div class = "tooltip-menu">
                    <ul><li class="sales_rep"><a href="#">Sales Rep 1</a></li>
                    <li class="sales_rep"><a href="#">Sales Rep 2</a></li>
                    <li class="last-child sales_rep"><a href="#">Sales Rep 3</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    </div>'> 
        <i class = 'fa fa-male ' aria-hidden='true'></i>    
    </a>
</td>
```

I want the tr index of the row, whose li item tooltip I clicked on.
javascript code

```
$('body').on('click', '.tooltip-menu li.sales_rep', function() {

    if(confirm("Have you chosen your sales rep?")){
        var sales_rep = $(this).find("a").html();

        //var $index = $(this).closest('a').closest('tr').index();
        var $index = $('#'+ $(this).data('for')).closest('tr').index();
    }
```

I tried this but this is not working, as it returns -1.
Please help

Comment: @Machavity It does have a closing tag. I did'nt understand which a you are talking about

Comment: it actually has. although data-title got an html property value.

Comment: @Machavity it does, at the end of the HTML in `data-title`

Comment: Uhm, nesting HTML within a tag attribute is a bad idea

Comment: For now, lets forget about standards, could you please help me get the index row ?

Comment: If that is all your javascript then look in the debugger console for javascript errors

Comment: No errors. The index value remains -1 though

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/97abdpzb/

Comment: @winghei The fiddle was posted by me for another part of the same problem. It does not offer a solution

Comment: now i see what you meant.  I am not sure what script you use to create the tooltip object. at least it should be created inside the <tr>. Or, somehow set a prop on your data-title(html template) where you can look up for an id.

Comment: @winghei It is created inside <tr>
I dont know of nay property  that you can set, to retrieve the id.

Comment: assuming u have one table, please  try `var $index = $('table tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));` otherwise add the id of that table.

Comment: @winghei.. No that doesnt work. It still returns -1

Comment: i guess you have to show the html code on `tr` tag with the tool-tip object created since the code above only gives hint on the tooltip html created but I dont know where the object was really created in DOM

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tooltip from jQuery UI, from my experience, the actual tooltip div is generated as a **sibling**, not a child, of the tooltip trigger element. That means that your tooltip menu is being generated as a sibling of your anchor (`a`), such that when you call `.closest('a')`, it will not return anything since the tooltip has no parents that match that selector.

Try `var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();`.